# Logarithmic terms in series expansions

Tags: logarithms, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Lately, I am encountering more and more example of series expansions that do include logarithmic terms.

For example (section 1 (page 3-5) in [hep-th/0002230](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002230)) when taking a scalar field on an asymptotic AdS background in Fefferman-Graham coordinates 
$$ds^2 = \frac{l^2}{r^2}(dr^2 + G_{ij}(x, r) dx^i dx^j)
$$
One can write a general asymptotic AdS spacetime in these coordinates as an expansion from the boundary $r \to \infty$, in which case on can write 
$$g(x, r) = g_{(0)} + r^2 g_{(2)} + \ldots + r^d g_{(d)} + h_{(d)} r^d \log r^2 + \mathcal{O}(r^{d+1})
$$
A scalar field on this background then looks, near the boundary at $r \to \infty$, as
$$
\Phi(x, r) = r^{d- \Delta} \left( \phi_{(0)} + r^2 \phi_{(2)} + \ldots + r^{2\Delta - d} \phi_{2\Delta-d} + r^{2\Delta-d} \log r^2 \psi_{(2\Delta-d)} \right)+ \mathcal{O}(r^{\Delta+1})
$$
Here I was initially somewhat surprised to see this logarithmic term. I vaguely understand that since we are expanding around $r \to \infty$ we need to take into account all different sorts of asymptotic behaviour (and thus also have to include asymptotic logarithmic behaviour).

I can however not find any rigorous explanation of this. If I define $z = 1/r$ and write a general expansion for $\Phi$ as an expansion around $z = 0$, how do I obtain again the logarithmic behaviour when I go back to $r = 1/z$?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main theme here is *[Singularity Analysis](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/Slides/berkeley04.pdf)* which describes the asymptotic behavior of a large class of functions with moderate growth and decay and the *strongly connected* asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of their generating functions. At first we recall the simpler

> **Rational and meromorphic functions:**
>
> When analysing rational and *[meromorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function)* locally near a singularity $\zeta$, the main factors are of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^{-r}\qquad\qquad r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}
> \end{align*}
>   Their coefficients involve asymptotically exponential-polynomials, i.e. finite linear combinations of elements of type 
>   \begin{align*}
> \zeta^{-n}n^{r-1}\qquad\qquad r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Functions with moderate growth and decay:**
>
> In singularity analysis we consider a much larger class of functions having other singularities than mere poles. The functions under consideration have as central elements of an expansion at a singularity $\zeta$ 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^{-\alpha}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\zeta}}\right)^\beta\qquad\qquad \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   These elements contribute asymptotically  terms of type
>   \begin{align*}
> \zeta^{-n}n^{\alpha-1}\left(\log n\right)^\beta
> \end{align*}
>
> We see depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have either powers or logarithmic contributions or both parts to consider.

**Table of functions:**

To better see the relationship a few functions together with their coefficients, exact and asymptotically.

\begin{array}{lll}
\text{function}\qquad&\qquad \text{coeff (exact)}\qquad & \quad\text{coeff (asymp.)}\\
\hline
\\
1-\sqrt{1-z}&\qquad\frac{2}{n4^n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}&\qquad\sim\quad\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi n^3}}\\
\\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}&\qquad\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}&\qquad\sim\quad\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\\
\\
\frac{1}{1-z}&\qquad1&\qquad\sim\quad1\\
\\
\frac{1}{1-z}\log\frac{1}{1-z}&\qquad H_n&\qquad\sim\quad\log n\\
\\
\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}&\qquad n+1&\qquad\sim\quad n\\
\end{array}

> **Functions addressed by OP:**
>
> If a function has multiple dominant singularities of type (1) the separate contributions of each of the singularities are to be added up, resulting in asymptotic expansions given by OP.

*Note:* The basic facts mentioned here are from the classic *[Analytic Combinatorics (chap. VI)](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick which contains a detailed elaboration of singularity analysis.