# How does one obtain series with logarithmic terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For some functions Wolfram|Alpha gives me series expansions which have some logarithmic terms. For example, for Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function $U(n,2,r)$ I [get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+in+r+hypergeometricU(n,2,r)):

$$U(n,2,r)=\frac1{(n-1)r\Gamma(n-1)}+\frac{\psi^{(0)}(n)+\color{red}{\log(r)}+2\gamma-1}{\Gamma(n-1)}+\cdots.$$

In general, what is the procedure to obtain such terms? I guess the $r^{-1}$ term could be obtained by Laurent expansion, but for the above function its usual formula for coefficients won't work due to the branch point.

Comment: For this special function you can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2#E9:  
$$U\left(a,n+1,z\right)=$$
$$\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n!\Gamma
\left(a-n\right)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(a\right)_{k}}
{\left(n+1\right)_{k}k!}z^{k}\left(\ln z+\psi \left(a+k\right)-\psi \left(1+k\right)- \psi\left(n+k+1\right)\right)$$
$$+\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(a\right)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(k-1)!\left(1-a+k\right)_{n-k}}{(n-k)!}z^{-k}$$

For a derivation see Lebedev, Special functions, Ch. 9.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an excerpt from *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1955006/logarithmic-terms-in-series-expansions/1970190#1970190)*.

> The main theme here is *[Singularity Analysis](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/Slides/berkeley04.pdf)* which describes the asymptotic behavior of a large class of functions with moderate growth and decay and the *strongly connected* asymptotic behavior of the coefficients of their generating functions.
>
> **Functions with moderate growth and decay:**
>
> The functions under consideration have as central elements of an expansion at a singularity $\zeta$ 
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(1-\frac{z}{\zeta}\right)^{-\alpha}\left(\log\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{\zeta}}\right)^\beta\qquad\qquad \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{C}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   These elements contribute asymptotically  terms of type
>   \begin{align*}
> \zeta^{-n}n^{\alpha-1}\left(\log n\right)^\beta
> \end{align*}
>
> We see depending on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we have either powers or logarithmic contributions or both parts to consider.

*Note:* The basic facts mentioned here are from the classic *[Analytic Combinatorics (chap. VI)](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick which contains a detailed elaboration of singularity analysis.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not sure that this could be the answer you expect.*

Consider $$y=U(n,2,r)\implies y'=-n\, U(n+1,3,r)$$ As you say, the development of $y'$ is a Laurent series but you can reduce to a Taylor series considering $r^2\,y'$ and get $$r^2\,y'=-\frac{1}{(n-1) \Gamma (n-1)}+\frac{r}{\Gamma (n-1)}-\frac{r^2 (n (-2 \psi
   ^{(0)}(n+1)-2 \log (r)-4 \gamma +3))}{4 \Gamma (n-1)}+O\left(r^3\right)$$ So $$y'=-\frac{1}{(n-1)  \Gamma (n-1)r^2}+\frac{1}{ \Gamma (n-1)r}-\frac{n (-2 \psi
   ^{(0)}(n+1)-2 \log (r)-4 \gamma +3)}{4 \Gamma (n-1)}+O\left(r\right)$$ and, integrating, $$y=\frac{1}{(n-1) r \Gamma (n-1)}+\frac{\log (r)}{\Gamma (n-1)}+\frac{n r (2 \psi
   ^{(0)}(n+1)+2 \log (r)+4 \gamma -5)}{4 \Gamma (n-1)}+O\left(r^2\right)$$ which can simplify to $$y=\frac{1}{r \Gamma (n)}+\frac{\log (r)}{\Gamma (n-1)}+\frac{n r \left(2 H_n+2 \log
   (r)+2 \gamma -5\right)}{4 \Gamma (n-1)}+O\left(r^2\right)$$

Comment: A series with $\log(r)$ in it doesn't look like a _Taylor_ series...

Comment: @Ruslan. I totally agree with you. What I wanted to show is how we arrive to. As I wrote, *I am not sure that this could be the answer you expect.* However, this expansion comes from a Taylor series (after a few tricks I sued).

Comment: The tricks you mention seem to be what I need from the answer. It'd be great if you described them in your answer.

Comment: @Ruslan. I used them in my answer : fom $y$ to $y'$, Laurent series for $y'$ or Taylor for $x^2 y'$ and integration of $y'$.

Comment: But _how_ do I get the $\log(r)$ term in Taylor series for $r^2y'$? I don't quite see how $n$th derivative at $r=0$ can give me a term with $r$.

Comment: @Ruslan. You are right and I am stupid ! It happens when using $O(r^3)$ not with  $O(r^2)$.